# Numpy: Quick setting of array elements

Tags: python, numpy

I just came across a showstopper for a part of my code and I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

I simply have a large data cube and want to change the maximum values along the z axis to some other number:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

x, y, z = 100, 100, 10
a = np.arange(x*y*z).reshape((z, y, x))

t = time()
a[np.argmax(a, axis=0)] = 1
print(time() - t)
```

This takes about 0.02s which is a bit slow for such a small array, but ok. My problem is that I need to do this with arrays as large as `(32, 4096, 4096)` and I have not had the patience to let this finish with the above code...it's just too inefficient, but it should actually be very fast! Am I doing something wrong with setting the array elements?

Comment: What's the time for just the `argmax`?

Comment: For the above example 0.001s, so just a fraction of the element setting part. For `(32, 4096, 4096)` it is 6.5s, so also ok. Actually I just noticed that this consumes quite a lot of memory...

Comment: You have a poor test case - it is too large, and the largest values are in the last `z` plane.  Try your method with a smaller random array?  Does it produce the right results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically indexing your numpy array with a numpy array containing numbers. I think that is the reason why it is so slow (and I'm not sure if it really does what you want it to do).

If you create a boolean numpy array and use this as slice it's orders of magnitudes faster.

For example:

```
pos_max = np.expand_dims(np.argmax(a, axis=0), axis=0)
pos_max_indices = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(10,1,1) == pos_max
a[pos_max_indices] = 1
```

is 20 times faster than the original and does the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is the indexing with numbers that's slowing it down.  Usually indexing a single dimension with a boolean vector is slower than indexing with the corresponding `np.where`.

Something else is going on here.  Look at these shapes:

```
In [14]: a.shape
Out[14]: (10, 100, 100)
In [15]: np.argmax(a,axis=0).shape
Out[15]: (100, 100)
In [16]: a[np.argmax(a,axis=0)].shape
Out[16]: (100, 100, 100, 100)
```

The indexed `a` is much larger than the original, 1000x.

@MSeifert's solution is faster, but I can't help feeling it is more complex than needed.

```
In [35]: %%timeit 
   ....: a=np.arange(x*y*z).reshape((z,y,x))
   ....: pos_max = np.expand_dims(np.argmax(a, axis=0), axis=0)
   ....: pos_max_indices = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(10,1,1) == pos_max
   ....: a[pos_max_indices]=1
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
```

I'm still working on an improvement.

The sample array isn't a good one - it's too big to display, and all the max values on the last `z` plane:

```
In [46]: x,y,z=4,2,3
In [47]: a=np.arange(x*y*z).reshape((z,y,x))
In [48]: a
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [49]: a[np.argmax(a,axis=0)]=1
In [50]: a
Out[50]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1]]])
```

I could access those same `argmax` values with:

```
In [51]: a[-1,...]
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Let's try a random array, where the argmax can be in any plane:

```
In [57]: a=np.random.randint(2,10,(z,y,x))
In [58]: a
Out[58]: 
array([[[9, 7, 6, 5],
        [6, 3, 5, 2]],

       [[5, 6, 2, 3],
        [7, 9, 6, 9]],

       [[7, 7, 8, 9],
        [2, 4, 9, 7]]])
In [59]: a[np.argmax(a,axis=0)]=0
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Oops - I turned everything to 0.  Is that what you want?

Let's try the `pos_max` method:

```
In [61]: a=np.random.randint(0,10,(z,y,x))
In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([[[9, 3, 9, 0],
        [6, 6, 2, 4]],

       [[9, 9, 4, 9],
        [5, 9, 7, 9]],

       [[1, 8, 1, 7],
        [1, 0, 2, 3]]])
In [63]: pos_max = np.expand_dims(np.argmax(a, axis=0), axis=0)
In [64]: pos_max
Out[64]: 
array([[[0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1]]], dtype=int32)
In [66]: pos_max_indices = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(z,1,1) == pos_max
In [67]: pos_max_indices
Out[67]: 
array([[[ True, False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
In [68]: a[pos_max_indices]=0
In [69]: a
Out[69]: 
array([[[0, 3, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 2, 4]],

       [[9, 0, 4, 0],
        [5, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 8, 1, 7],
        [1, 0, 2, 3]]])
```

That looks more reasonable.  There still is a `9` in the 2nd plane, but that's because there was also a `9` in the 1st.

---

This still needs to be cleaned up, but here's a non-boolean mask solution:

```
In [98]: a=np.random.randint(0,10,(z,y,x))
In [99]: a1=a.reshape(z,-1)   # it's easier to work with a 2d view
In [100]: ind=np.argmax(a1,axis=0)
In [101]: ind
Out[101]: array([2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [102]: a1[ind,np.arange(a1.shape[1])]  # the largest values
Out[102]: array([9, 8, 7, 4, 9, 7, 9, 6])
In [104]: a1
Out[104]: 
array([[3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7, 4, 5],
       [4, 4, 7, 1, 3, 7, 9, 4],
       [9, 8, 3, 3, 9, 1, 2, 6]])

In [105]: a1[ind,np.arange(a1.shape[1])]=0
In [106]: a
Out[106]: 
array([[[3, 1, 5, 0],
        [2, 0, 4, 5]],

       [[4, 4, 0, 1],
        [3, 7, 0, 4]],

       [[0, 0, 3, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 0]]])
```

Working with `a1` the 2d view is easier; the exact shape of the `x,y` dimensions is not important to this problem.  We are changing individual values, not columns or planes.  Still I'd like to do get it working without `a1.

---

Here are two functions that replace the maximum value (in the 1st plane).  I use `copy` since it makes repeated time testing easier.

```
def setmax0(a, value=-1):
    # @MSeifert's
    a = a.copy()
    z = a.shape[0]
    # a=np.arange(x*y*z).reshape((z,y,x))
    pos_max = np.expand_dims(np.argmax(a, axis=0), axis=0)
    pos_max_indices = np.arange(z).reshape(z,1,1) == pos_max
    a[pos_max_indices]=value
    return a

def setmax1(a, value=-2):
    a = a.copy()
    z = a.shape[0]
    a1 = a.reshape(z, -1)
    ind = np.argmax(a1, axis=0)
    a1[ind, np.arange(a1.shape[1])] = value
    return a
```

They produce the same result in a test like:

```
ab = np.random.randint(0,100,(20,1000,1000))
test = np.allclose(setmax1(ab,-1),setmax0(ab,-1))
```

Timings (using `ipython` `timeit`) are basically the same.

They do assign values in different orders, so `setmax0(ab,-np.arange(...))` will be different.

Comment: The integer indexing triggers [advanced slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) and that's a) not what was intended and b) very slow due to the number of operations that triggers. Maybe I should have explained it in more details. :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking a closer look at this! If you find a way to speed things even more up, please share it 

Comment: boolean indexing is also advanced. Basic indexing uses slices.

Comment: That's right. I've worked with boolean masks so regularly I totally forgot about it.